# After changing the url in .htaccess php is not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I changed this url
 http://localhost/rozgar/job.php?search=Testing%201&id=43
 to this 
http://localhost/rozgar/job/Testing%201/43
by using .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^job/([A-Za-z]+) job.php?id=$1&search=$2
```

Link is working fine but php is not loading data from database it's showing me error..

```
    <?php
include "inc/db.php";
$id = @$_GET['id'];
$search = @$_GET['search'];
session_start();
$email = @$_SESSION['email'];

  $id=@$_GET['id'];
  $query="select * from company,jobs where company.id = jobs.company_id AND jobs.id = '$id'";
$run=mysqli_query($db,$query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)) {
}
```

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com - Learm about SQL injection and how to prevent them.

Answer (score 0):

you have to try this rule. You have passed value only for search field but you also passed value for id  like (0-9). so then your htaccess rule make like below.

```
RewriteRule ^job/([A-Za-z-]+)/([0-9]+) job.php?search=$1&id=$2
```

After this you can cehck it out this url.

```
 http://localhost/rozgar/job/testing/43
```

And remember one thing you should not pass value in url which have space like "testing 002" the your htaccess rule break. For this you have to convert space in to underscore.

Comment: how to convert spaces into underscore?

Comment: using the php function str_replace(" ","_","Hello world!");;

Answer (score 0):

Just create .htaccess like this

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]


RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ job.php?id=$1&search=$2 [L,QSA]
```

And Now get the get variable in job.php